# Select from TWO sql tables, rooms and image with first table show all the query second table no

Tags: mysql, join, select

I have 2 tables, rooms and images, and I want to show rows with all the rooms I have for that specific hotel and also show me the each images from the rooms, but the problems is when I use JOIN SELECT is show me 8 rows from all the queries from the second tables, which means is showing me 3 times(i have 3 images for this room) the single room and 5 times the double rooms (i have 5 images for this room) **so is showing me 8 rows**, and **I want only 2 rows** for each rooms with each images - 3 and 5

```
table 1 - rooms
id, id_hotel, type_room
1, 1, single
2, 2, double

table 2 - images
id, id_rooms, url
1, 1, image-A.jpg
2, 1, image-b.jpg
3, 1, image C.jpg
4, 2, image D.jpg
5, 2, IMAGE E.jpg
6, 2, IMAGE f.jpg
7, 2, IMAGE g.jpg
8, 2, IMAGE h.jpg
```

How I can Do?? I tried also RIGHT JOIN and LEFT JOIN ... other solution?

Comment: What are your expected results?  If you want to put all the images in a single column, use `group_concat`...

Comment: Show us the query you try, and the result you want. `I want only 2 rows` is very vague on what is the expected result

Comment: I want to show me 2 big rows for each ROOMS and in that rows to show me a carousel for image for the specifically  IMAGEs, so show me a room single with 3 image in a carousel and double room rows with 5 images, but is showing me 8 rows for each image...

Comment: Its called pivot table. This has all the info you'll need: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7674786/1543677

Comment: Again show us on the question what result you want. We are not mind readers and sql doesn't know what a carousel does. So you need to explain what structure you need for your carousel to work

Comment: can you show me a exemple with my situation??, i watched at pivot table but to be honest I did not understand nothing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: same row `<h3>echo type_room / single</h3><div><img src="echo url-image A"><img src="echo url-image b"><img src="echo url-image c"></div>` something like this i want to show me a row, but the problem is the row give me something like this `<h3>echo type_room / single</h3><div><img src="echo url-image A"></div>` row 1

Comment: as sgeddes said, you need `GROUP_CONCAT`

Comment: I see no query here

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this?

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/QHIMVL66872)**

```
SELECT `id_rooms`, GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT('<img src="',`url`,'>') SEPARATOR '') as i
FROM images
GROUP BY `id_rooms`;
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: no I want something like this  from the 2 tables    `` +----------+---------+----------------------------+
|  rows  | id_rooms    |   url | +----------+---------+----------------------------+
|        1 |   single|   <div class="carousel"><img src="image-A.jpg"><img src="image-b.jpg"><img src="image-c.jpg"></div>                   |
+----------+---------+----------------------------+
|        2 |   double|    <div class="carousel"><img src="image-D.jpg"><img src="image-E.jpg"><img src="image-F.jpg"><img src="image-G.jpg"></div>                |
+----------+---------+-------------------+``